# I need Coefficientlist for Trigonometric function

Tags: coefficients

I have an expression:

expr= A*Sin[x]*Tan[x]+B*Csc[x/2]*Sin[x]+Cot[x\2]^2+...

Expression contains all trigonometric functions with different angles.

I need coefficientlist for all different trigonometric functions.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question:

Comment: expr= A*Sin[x]Tan[x/2]+BCsc[x/2]*Sin[x/2]+Cot[x\2]^2+...

Expression contains all type of trigonometric functions with SAME angle.

I need coefficientlist for the expression,